# JButton ActionListener general inquiry

Tags: java, swing, class, jbutton, actionlistener

Coming out of high school a few years ago, I've always been taught two ways to add an `ActionListener` to a `JButton`. One way is like this:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("My Button!");
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //actions here
    }
});
```

Another way is like this:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("My Button");
myButton.addActionListener(new myButtonAction());
```

Then somewhere at the bottom of my code, I would add this:

```
class myButtonAction implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //actions here
    }
}
```

My question today is, is there anyway I can write another sourcefile (a `.java`) and just write my entire method in there? I'd want to be able to perform actions from my original `class` file, we'll call it `myButtonClass` for the sake of this example. Would I be able to use variables like `int` `double` `String` and components like `Properties` `JProgressBar` `JPanel` and `JTextArea` from my original class and manipulate them and send them back to my original class from my `myButtonClass`?

If so, would you mind helping me and shoving an example? How would I call the `myButtonClass` to the `JButton`?

Let me know if my questions is misleading or unclear.

Comment: you mean class myButtonAction as an external java file? sure you can

Comment: Would you mind helping me and showing me how I would put it in an external java file and still be able to use variables from the original java file?

Comment: class myButton extends JButton implements actionListener {}? Just like an applet but not an applet. I did this for Jpanel.

Comment: if I say `class myButton extends JButton implements actionListener{}`, would I still call `JButton` or would that be replaced with my original java file. so `class myButton extends originalClass implements actionListener{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want :

```
public class MyClass {

    public void myMethod() {

        JButton myButton = new JButton("My Button");
        myButton.addActionListener(new myButtonAction(this));
    }

    public void anotherMethod() {

    }

}
```

and

```
public class myButtonAction implements ActionListener{

    private MyClass mc;

    public myButtonAction(MyClass mc) {
        this.mc = mc;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      mc.anotherMethod();
    }
}
```

you need to pass the class through the contructor

Comment: This works exactly as I want it to. Thank you so much for sharing your example.